How to confirm that these tensor-product matrices commute
So I want to show that these "stabilizer operators" commute.
These operators are the tensor products of $8$ $2 \times 2$ matrices. As such the operators themselves are $256 \times 256$ matrices.
For example:
$Z=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\\ 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$ and $I= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$
My first operator $S_{1}$ is defined as $S_{1}=Z \otimes Z \otimes Z \otimes Z \otimes I \otimes I \otimes I \otimes I$
My second operator $S_{2}$ is defined as $S_{2}= Z \otimes Z \otimes I \otimes I \otimes Z \otimes Z \otimes I \otimes I$
I know that these operators $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ commute but for some reason, I cannot get mathematica to confirm that they commute.
My code is as follows:
I = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}
Z = {{1, 0}, {0, -1}}

S1 = KroneckerProduct[Z, Z, Z, Z, I, I, I, 
  I]

S2 = KroneckerProduct[Z, Z, I, I, Z, Z, I, 
  I]

TrueQ[S1.S2=S2.S1]

But this keeps returning FALSE, even though I know that they commute?

Did you notice that this code spit out errors when you tried to run it? It told you that the symbol I is protected.  Always use lower-case letters for the names of built-in functions in Mathematica. Use i instead of I. i = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}; Z = {{1, 0}, {0, -1}}; S1 = KroneckerProduct[Z, Z, Z, Z, i, i, i, i]; S2 = KroneckerProduct[Z, Z, i, i, Z, Z, i, i]; S1.S2 == S2.S1 yields True.  A good rule of thumb is to pay attention to errors, and also check to make sure that your code is doing what you think it is.  For instance, run I on its own to see what it's spitting out.

Hi, I had actually called them Zpauli and Id but changed it when writing into the stack exchange for the sake of simplicity, which I see now was a bad idea as they are protected symbols!  But I see my mistake was using a single equals sign $=$ instead of a double one "==". Thanks for the help!

Equality is == not = in TrueQ[S1.S2=S2.S1]

Fix the problems mentioned in the comments and it works
b = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
Z = {{1, 0}, {0, -1}};
S1 = KroneckerProduct[Z, Z, Z, Z, b, b, b, b];
S2 = KroneckerProduct[Z, Z, b, b, Z, Z, b, b];
TrueQ[S1 . S2 == S2 . S1]

(* True *)

